# JavaScript canvas, scale between two points on chart/graph?

Tags: javascript, charts

So I've built a small graph application with JavaScript to help me practice using the canvas. I've spent the last 10 hours trying to scale between two points on the X-Axis and can't for the life of me figure it out. I've learned that to scale you need to translate > scale > translate. This works fine when I scale to the far left/right using the following type code.

```
let x = 0;
let y = this.getCanvasHeight() / 2;

this.getCanvasContext().clearRect(0, 0, this.getCanvas().width, this.getCanvas().height);
this.setCanvas();
ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.scale(scale, 1);
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
this.resetCanvasLines();
this.renderGraph(this.state.points, scale);
```

This piece of code simply allows me to zoom into the far left of the graph. So now I'm trying to pick two points on this graph and zoom in on top of them, so that they fit evenly on the screen. The Y-Axis will always be the same.

My thinking was to get the midpoint between the two points and zoom in on that location, which I feel should work but I just can't get it working. My graph width is 3010px and split into 5 segments of 602px. I want to zoom let's say from x1 = 602 and x2 = 1806, which has the midpoint of 1204. Is there a technique to properly calculating the scale amount?

```
rangeFinder(from, to) {
  let points = this.state.points;
  if (points.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  let ctx = this.getCanvasContext();
  let canvasWidth = this.getCanvasWidth();
  let canvasHeight = this.getCanvasHeight() / 2;
  let seconds = this.state.seconds;
  let second = canvasWidth / seconds;
  let scale = 1;
  // My graph starts from zero, goes up to 5 and the values are to represent seconds. 
  // This gets the pixel value for the fromX value.
  let fromX = from * second;
  to = isNaN(to) ? 5 : to;

  // Get the pixel value for the to location. 
  let toX = parseInt(to) * second;
  let y = canvasHeight / 2;

  // get the midpoint between the two points.
  let midpoint = fromX + ((toX - fromX) / 2);

  // This is where I really go wrong. I'm trying to calculate the scale amount
  let zoom = canvasWidth - (toX - fromX);
  let zoomPixel = (zoom / 10) / 1000;
  let scaleAmount = scale + ((zoom / (canvasWidth / 100)) / 100) + zoomPixel;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.getCanvas().width, this.getCanvas().height);
  this.setCanvas();

  // translate and scale.
  ctx.translate(midpoint, y);
  ctx.scale(scaleAmount, 1);
  ctx.translate(-midpoint, -y);

  this.resetCanvasLines();
  this.renderGraph(points);

}
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale = 5/3 = total width / part width.
After scale, x = 602 should have moved to 602 * 5/3 ~ 1000. Translate the new image by -1000. There is no need to find mid-point.

Comment: Vijay you genius, that worked perfectly. My calculation was way off! Its a good Job your not standing in front of me, because I'd high five so hard I may just break your wrist. Thanks so much man!